# configure: error: You need libxml2 >= 2.6.5 to compile theforgottenserver!

Tags: libxml

I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Despite the fact that I have the latest version of libxml2 (2.9.10 + dfsg-2 + ubuntu16.04.1 + deb.sury.org + 1) I am still getting the following error

```
configure: error: You need libxml2 >= 2.6.5 to compile theforgottenserver!
```

Comment: Is the libxml2-**dev** package installed?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading to version 2.6.5 to see if that works?

Comment: @steeldriver - yes.
Gordster - How downgrading?

Comment: What is theforgottenserver? How we can download it?

Comment: @N0rbert - Theforgottenserver is a game engine. How can I change to a lower version of libxml2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was available [only for ArchLinux](https://repology.org/project/forgottenserver/versions).

For Ubuntu you have to follow the official [Compiling on Ubuntu](https://github.com/otland/forgottenserver/wiki/Compiling-on-Ubuntu) guide:

> **1. Install the required software**
>   `sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential liblua5.2-dev libgmp3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libpugixml-dev libcrypto++-dev`
>
> **2. Download the source code**
>   `git clone --recursive https://github.com/otland/forgottenserver.git`
>
> **3. Generate the build files**
>
> ```
> cd forgottenserver
> mkdir build && cd build
> cmake ..
> ```
>
> **4. Build**
>
> ```
> make
> ```

Comment: I know you have given a good configuration, but I have a different engine and it requires libxml2, the game engine is paid. On one VPS (DEBIAN 8) the engine compiled correctly, and on Ubuntu 16 this error pops up, something like it can't find libxml2

Comment: .... Then install "libxml2" as already said above : `sudo apt install libxml2-dev`

Comment: Install, and not work ;/

Comment: I did exactly as per this answer and it worked fine. I searched everything for keywords to try to find the error print and such, with no results. Conclusion: this has something to do with the paid version and the issue does not exist in the free version. Therefore ask for support from them.